# Jquery append a suffix to a string and move cursor to the left

Tags: jquery

I have a text input box that I would like to automatically add 'inches' as a suffix to user inputs either when they click on the box or while typing. So basically when a user enters input into the box the word inches will appear to the right of their cursor, but their cursor will remain to the left of the in suffix.  I tried using the [autonumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) library, which does this sort of thing quite well, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to allow slashes for fractions.  Below is a sort of example with | representing the edges of the box and ^ representing the cursor.

```
| 1/2^ inches |
```

or

```
| ^ inches |
```

Comment: Could you add "  inches" and then simulate a stroke of the `HOME` key all while inside the input box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rtqsw/).

The trick is to add "inches" to the value of the input and then move the cursor accordingly with the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` attributes.

Javascript:

```
$("#mytext").on("click keyup", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var output = value.substring(0, value.length - 7) + " inches";
    var cursorPosition = output.length - 7;
    $(this).val(output);
    $(this)[0].selectionStart = $(this)[0].selectionEnd = cursorPosition;
});
```